# its my html form I have used Ajax in it. now I need to clear the data in the form after submitting it by pressing the submit button

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>employee_good</title>
    <style>
        div {
            display: inline-table;
            width: 49%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script>
    function loadData() {
        loadEmployee();
        loadGender();
    }

    function loadEmployee() {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //console.log(this.readyState);
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var jsonData = this.responseText;
                showTable(jsonData);
            }
        }

        http.open("GET", "../server/employee.php", true);
        http.send();
    }

    function loadGender() {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //console.log(this.readyState);
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var jsonData = this.responseText;
                showGender(jsonData);
            }
        }

        http.open("GET", "../server/gender.php", true);
        http.send();
    }
    function showGender(jsonData) {
        var genders = JSON.parse(jsonData);

        for (let i = 0; i < genders.length; i++) {
            const gender = genders[i];

            var txtOption = document.createElement("option");
            txtOption.innerHTML = gender['name'];
            txtOption.value = gender['id'];

            cmbGender.appendChild(txtOption);
        }
    }
    function showTable(jsonData) {

        display.innerHTML = "";
        var employees = JSON.parse(jsonData);

        for (let i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
            const employee = employees[i];

            var tr = document.createElement("tr");
            var tdId = document.createElement("td");
            tdId.innerHTML = employee['id'];
            tr.appendChild(tdId);

            var tdName = document.createElement("td");
            tdName.innerHTML = employee['name'];
            tr.appendChild(tdName);

            var tdAge = document.createElement("td");
            tdAge.innerHTML = employee['age'];
            tr.appendChild(tdAge);

            var tdGender = document.createElement("td");
            tdGender.innerHTML = employee['gender'];
            tr.appendChild(tdGender);

            var tdDelete = document.createElement("td");
            var btnDelete = document.createElement("input");
            btnDelete.value = "Delete";
            btnDelete.type = "button";
            btnDelete.addEventListener("click", function () {
                deleteEmployee(employee['id']);
            })
            tdDelete.appendChild(btnDelete);
            tr.appendChild(tdDelete);

            display.appendChild(tr);
        }
    }

    function deleteEmployee(id) {
        window.alert(id);
        //write delete function 
    }

    function addEmployee() {
        var name = txtName.value;
        var age = txtAge.value;
        var gender = cmbGender.value;
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                if (this.responseText === "true") {
                    loadEmployee();
                }
            }
        }

        http.open("POST", "../server/insert.php", true);
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.send("txtName=" + name + "&txtAge=" + age + "&txtGender=" + gender);
    }
</script>

<body onload="loadData()">
    <div>
        <h1>Add Employee</h1>

        <form>
            Enter Name:
            <input type="text" id="txtName">
            <br><br>
            Enter Age:
            <input type="text" id="txtAge">
            <br><br>
            Select Gender:
            <select id="cmbGender">

            </select>
            <br><br>
            <input type="button" value="Clear">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="addEmployee()">
        </form>

    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Employee Table</h1>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="display">
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the form inputs after the XHR is completed. The following would be one way of doing it.

```
function addEmployee() {
    var name = txtName.value;
    var age = txtAge.value;
    var gender = cmbGender.value;
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (this.responseText === "true") {
                loadEmployee();
                resetForm();
            }
        }
    }

    http.open("POST", "../server/insert.php", true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send("txtName=" + name + "&txtAge=" + age + "&txtGender=" + gender);
}

function resetForm() {
    var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#txtName, #txtAge'), select = document.getElementById('cmbGender');
    inputs.forEach(input => {
        input.value = '';
    });
    select.innerHTML = '';        
}
```

Hope that helped.